# How to use `transition-group` with custom tag and class

Tags: vue.js

I need to render a div with `item` class

```
<div class="ui horizontal list">
    <transition-group name="custom-classes-transition” enter-active-class="animated fadeInLeft" leave-active-class="animated fadeOutLeft">
        <div class="item" v-for="(filter, filterIndex) in filters" :key="filterIndex”> .. </div>
    </transition-group>
</div>
```

`.item` should be directly nested of `.ui.list`

I try to add `tag="div”` but this add a new div with my `div.item`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply add a `class` prop to your `transition-group`.

Example:

```
<transition-group class="ui horizontal list" name="custom-classes-transition" enter-active-class="animated fadeInLeft" leave-active-class="animated fadeOutLeft">
    <div class="item" v-for="(filter, filterIndex) in filters" :key="filterIndex"> .. </div>
</transition-group>
```